# How can set \rule after \section if \section is renew?

Tags: sectioning, rules, sections-paragraphs

How can I set `\rule` after `\section` if `\section` is renewed?

This doesn't work:

```
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}{%
        \newpage%
        \oldsection%
            \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}%
    }
```

This works, but the line is before title:

```
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}{%
        \newpage%
        \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}%
            \oldsection%
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is because `\section` takes some arguments, and these arguments have to be read before you can place the horizontal rule. You can use [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to help capture the arguments first and then decide on the type of sectioning you want to do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{s o m}{%
  \clearpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \Section*
      \section*{#3}%
    }{% \Section
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {% \Section[]{}
          \section[#2]{#3}%
        }{% \Section{}
          \section{#3}%
        }%
    }%
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{4pt}\par\noindent
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\Section{A section}\lipsum[1-3]
\Section{Another section}\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

The `{s o m}` macro identifier requests an (optional) `s`tar, an `o`ptional argument and a `m`andatory argument. So, something of the form `\Section*[..]{...}` and branches accordingly using the conditionals `\IfBooleanTF` and `\IfNoValueTF`.

Of course, this is a very elementary example. You can play around with the spacing of the horizontal rule. Also, other packages allow does this kind of thing for you automatically, like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty), for example.

Comment: ou, my text is renerated by pandoc, I can't use Newcommand. Ok, let see on titlerec

thx for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]          
  {\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\textup{\thesection}}% label
  {0.5em}%                sep     
  {}%                     before        
  [\titlerule]%           after    
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}  
This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```